# Unable to install rails on jRuby

Tags: windows, rubygems, installation, jruby, jrubyonrails

What I have installed until now is:

1. Latest JDK and JRE (version 7 update 6)
2. jRuby 1.7.0 preview 2

and successfully tested them.

Then I try the following command:

```
jruby -S gem install -y rails
```

and get the following error:

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... <RuntimeError>
    Unknown command itall
```

Please advice, what I have to do in order to install rails on jruby. My OS is windows pro (32 bits).

EDIT: Also note that I have not install any other thing - Ruby for example.

Comment: Would you meant "Unknown command install" instead of "Unknown command itall" ? - Please check: "jruby -S gem ENV" and report here the output you get

Comment: When I remove the '-y' part of the command the install happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the '-y' part of the command fix the issue.